# Property 'isiOSOnMac' not found on object of type 'NSProcessInfo'

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am having this issue on specific system only(Mac mini). how can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See [How do I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Consider [taking a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please provide your code with your question, along with your thinking, expectations, and the steps you took

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to comment that block of code where you are having this error.
after that you are able to make a build successfully.